# How to resolve this neo4j/python error, my query is working fine in neo4j UI but getting this error here

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher

This is the code I am trying to run

```
def get_label(tx, name): 
tx.run("Match(n) where n.name=$name" 
     "return labels(n)",
      name=name )
return "labels(n)"

with graphdb.session() as session:
    Label = session.read_transaction(get_label, "usa")
```

I am getting this syntax error:

> neo4j.exceptions.CypherSyntaxError: {code:
> Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError} {message: Invalid input 'a':
> expected 'o/O' (line 1, column 36 (offset: 35)) "Match(n) where
> n.name=$namereturn labels(n)" ^}

Answer (score 1):

First, you're missing a space or newline between `$name` and `return` in your query.
It should be:

```
"MATCH (n) WHERE n.name = $name RETURN labels(n)"
```

or even shorter:

```
"MATCH (n {name: $name}) RETURN labels(n)"
```

Second, you're not returning the results of `tx.run`, you're returning a string. I'm not experienced in Python but the code should probably be more like:

```
def get_label(tx, name): 
    return list(tx.run("MATCH (n {name: $name}) RETURN labels(n)", name=name))
```

Finally, `get_label` is probably a misnomer.
A node defines 0 to many labels and the implementation I suggested here would return as many lists of labels as there are matched nodes.
This might mean a single list if the name is unique among all nodes in your data set.